# How are the newly discovered Janus/Epimetheus rings different from the other rings of Saturn?

Tags: saturn, planetary-ring

What are the newly discovered ring systems of Saturn, and the circumstances relating to the discovery? Is there something that makes them different from the old well-known rings, like their formation?

The ring in question is the [Janus/Epimetheus ring system](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA08322):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/science/moons/epimetheus/

Scientists believe the ring formation was due to the break up of one moon. Cassini has taken photographs of the moons and Voyager was the satellite to allow scientists to discover the moons and the rings which follow their orbit. What is seemingly special about these rings is the structure.

http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/photos/imagedetails/index.cfm?imageId=2277

Comment: What's the structure like?

Comment: Links are dead.